# VS Code: Find: permanently enable regular expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm evaluating VS Code as a replacement for Sublime Text.  In Sublime, after I've enabled regular expressions in the find dialog, that option remains turned on until I turn it off, even after quit and restart.

In VS Code it defaults to off every time I start the application.  I'd really like it to always be turned on; it's a rare situation where I need to search for something containing special characters and I *don't* want regexes enabled.

Is there any way to get that option to be persistent across sessions (meaning each time the application is terminated and restarted)?

I've searched the settings for "find", "regex", "expressions", and "replace" and I don't see any such setting.

MacOS version 10.13.6

VS Code version 1.25.1

Comment: Please better define "session" in your context.  If I set Find to Regex, close Code and reopen it, it's still set to Regex.  I'm using the latest Code, on Windows 10.  Which version of Code are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: Updated the question with those clarifications

Comment: How you run vscode? I'm runing it from console by `code .` and it remember search settings. (But I'm working on windows)

Comment: I'm running it on Mac and I use the `code` command in terminal a lot, but it's probably inconsistent how I initially launch it from one boot to the next, and I almost never quit the application, but reboots aren't uncommon.  It never occurred to me that it might use different settings depending on how it's launched..

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. When I open a new instance of code, I always have to enable "Use Regular Expressions". Fortunately, this is a matter of "Alt+R" and so is not bad, but it get's annoying to have to press it, as I often don't remember if I'm restarting VSCode or if I have had the application opened for a while.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 If you run VSCode from a different directory, does it still remember the search settings? For me, it forgets them for any new directory, which is extremely frustrating.